# Open page in the same tab html via javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write a code to match username and password. If both are right, it must be redirected to a new page and if it is wrong, it must give an alert message. When the password is correct and when I click on submit, it open the success message in a new tab, i want it to be displayed in the same tab.

```
    function redirectPage(form) {
    if (form.uname.value == 'test' && form.uname.value == 'test') {
       window.open('login.html');
    } else {
      alert("Wrong Credentials, Try again")
    }
```

PS

```
       window.open('login.html','_self');
```

isnt working

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
window.location.replace("login.html");
```

Comment: Tried, That isn't working too. It just refreshes my current page.

Comment: You have to be on a different page and add this code. When the condition is reached, it will redirect to "login.html"

Comment: The initial code is on "index.html" and when this line is reached, it should be redirected to "login.html"

Comment: There is something else going on on your code. It should work perfectly. Please post your rest of the HTML and Javascript on the page